# bigcommerce php silex hello world installation error

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am setting up hello world silex app in my localhost and HTTPS is enabled, but installation process is not successful. What am I doing wrong? I have done app configuration in store too.

Comment: I'm quite sure nobody can guess this without the details

Comment: https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

Comment: /callback url not found